# Column named id cannot be found. Parameter name: columnName in vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

Error when am trying to second delete or second update of row in datagrid view, am using microsoft visual basic 2010 and ms access db 2013

```
Private Sub delete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles delete.Click
    'check for the selected data
    If Me.dgvData.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim intStdID As Integer = Me.dgvData.SelectedRows(0).Cells("id").Value
        'open connection
        If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Open()
        End If

        'close connection
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM students WHERE ID=" & intStdID
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'refresh data
        Me.refreshData()

        'close connection
        con.Close()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the schema of the table students?

Comment: @Steve, students(ID,firstName,lastName,dob,gender)

Comment: Well, unless you have changed the connection, that code should work. Try using the debugger to see the value of the intStdID and the value of con.ConnectionString when you get the error.

Comment: @steve, it seems that first time i delete it work but second time doesnot work and the value of intStdID is 0

Comment: What does the call to refreshData? Could you add it to your question above?

Comment: it worked, the problem is my refreshData(), I  remove Me.clear.PerformClick() which cleared my intStdID when i firstly delete, thnx

Comment: The devil is always hidden in details.